# Solr Image Result

Tags: solr, google-books

I am new to Solr for providing search results.

I am planning to implement something similar to google books, which highlight search words in result-set and make an image from result ... So I need to have a clue to how to make an image from result, out from solr.

Comment: cross-posted to solr-user: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-Image-Result-td2039638.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

itext pdf library for highlighting